# How to create a grid of images using Masonry?

Tags: html, css, masonry

I am still a beginner at web development so I need some help implementing Masonry. How can I apply Masonry to multiple images to create a photo grid similar to Tumblr's design? Is there a way to do this with just HTML and CSS?

Comment: Check this article, it should help https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Answer (score 0):

To create a masonry layout with CSS Grid is very easy today. I would recommend you look at https://labs.jensimmons.com/#imagegallery to see how it has been done.

https://gridbyexample.com/ is also a good place to learn about CSS grid.